try-runtime Report Zero Weight Despite Successful Migration Execution in Polkadot 1.0
We are currently using node-template based on Polkadot 1.0 and testing a storage migration with try-runtime. We've successfully conducted several migrations in the past, but this time we're encountering an issue where the weight returned by Executive::try_runtime_upgrade(checks).unwrap(); is 0.
Our implementation of on_runtime_upgrade in the TryRuntime trait looks like this:
#[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
impl frame_try_runtime::TryRuntime<Block> for Runtime {
    fn on_runtime_upgrade(checks: frame_try_runtime::UpgradeCheckSelect) -> (Weight, Weight) {
        let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade(checks).unwrap();
        log::info!("Finished runtime upgrade with weight: {}", weight);
        (weight, BlockWeights::get().max_block)
    }
}

The migration logic itself seems to be working correctly, as logging within the migration function shows that the proper weight is being calculated and returned. However, when running try-runtime, even though the migration logic is triggered, the reported runtime ref_time consumed is 0.
End of logs:
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z DEBUG wasm-heap] allocator dropped: AllocationStats { bytes_allocated: 56, bytes_allocated_peak: 696, bytes_allocated_sum: 336360, address_space_used: 1312 }
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z DEBUG try-runtime::cli] Proof: 0x5ed41e5e16056765bc84... / 1201 nodes
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z DEBUG try-runtime::cli] Encoded proof size: 147.0 KB
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z DEBUG try-runtime::cli] Compact proof size: 108.3 KB
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] PoV size (zstd-compressed compact proof): 66.6 KB. For parachains, it's your responsibility to verify that a PoV of this size fits within any relaychain constraints.
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] Consumed ref_time: 0s (0.00% of max 2s)
2024-08-21T23:30:31Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] ✅ No weight safety issues detected. Please note this does not guarantee a successful runtime upgrade. Always test your runtime upgrade with recent state, and ensure that the weight usage of your migrations will not drastically differ between testing and actual on-chain execution.

We tried to pass --checks=none and --checks=all to on-runtime-upgrade, but the result remains the same—0 weight is reported, even though the migration logic is executed always as expected.
The migration file can be found here.
We use the use try-runtime-core 0.7.0
and run it with
RUST_LOG=debug try-runtime --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/tfchain-runtime/tfchain_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm on-runtime-upgrade --checks=none live --uri ws://10.10.0.55:9944

What should we check or investigate to resolve this issue?

It was caused by a bug in try_on_runtime_upgrade with the cumulative weight in Polkadot v1.0.0, which was resolved in Polkadot v1.1.0.
Refer to the v1.1.0 release notes:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/releases/tag/polkadot-v1.1.0
Check out the related PR:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/14793
Upgrading to version 1.1.0 resolves the issue.

Did you try --disable-idempotency-checks.
The migration will be tested multiple times by default. And I saw such line https://github.com/threefoldtech/tfchain/blob/04fd0e7636abf52a59b05d203e1e507e6b8a132d/substrate-node/pallets/pallet-smart-contract/src/migrations/v12.rs#L51.

Yes, with no luck.
